# Why does this return "index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" when I divide but it's fine for subtraction? (argrelextrema, pandas)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

This code is designed to correct a thin film spectrum from a reference spectrum, find mins and maxes, and plot the corrected spectrum.

In the subtraction case, it works fine:

```
corrected_power = pd.DataFrame(spec_film["Power (W)"] - spec_ref["Power (W)"], columns = ["Power (W)"])

corrected_spec = corrected_power.join(spec_film["Wavelength (nm)"])

###############Find local maxima ###################

local_max = np.array(argrelextrema(corrected_power.values, np.greater_equal, order=10))

#find corresponding power values for the local maxima

local_max = np.array([x*2+400 for x in local_max][0]), np.zeros(len(local_max[0]))

local_maxes = np.transpose(np.array([np.zeros(len(local_max[0])),list(local_max[0])]))

i = 0

# take the power values for the max wavelengths in local_max and put them in a new list

for elem in local_max[0]:
    local_maxes[i,0] = corrected_spec.loc[corrected_spec["Wavelength (nm)"] == elem].values[0,0]
    i += 1

______

The maxima are:[ 406.  438.  506.  612.  762.  938. 1000.]
The minima are:[420. 472. 554. 670. 830. 966.]
```

However, when I divide instead of subtract, I get a out of bounds error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-5d7219828f63> in <module>
     47 
     48 for elem in local_max[0]:
---> 49     local_maxes[i,0] = corrected_spec.loc[corrected_spec["Wavelength (nm)"] == float(elem)].values[0,0]
     50     i += 1
     51 

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Strangely, finding minima works in both cases, which is done with the exact same block of code as above:

```
local_min = np.array(argrelextrema(corrected_power.values, np.less_equal, order=10))

local_min = np.array([x*2+400 for x in local_min][0]), np.zeros(len(local_min[0]))

local_mins = np.transpose(np.array([np.zeros(len(local_min[0])),list(local_min[0])]))

i = 0

# take the power values for the min wavelengths in local_max and put them in a new list

for elem in local_min[0]:
    local_mins[i,0] = corrected_spec.loc[corrected_spec["Wavelength (nm)"] == elem].values[0,0]
    i += 1
```

I thought this might mean that .loc is not finding any values, but I tried a few manually and it found them.

I checked that before the for elem in local_(max/min)[0] is run, both arrays look the same:

```
local max = (array([400, 438, 506, 612, 762, 986], dtype=int64), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])) length =  2
local maxes = [[  0. 400.]
 [  0. 438.]
 [  0. 506.]
 [  0. 612.]
 [  0. 762.]
 [  0. 986.]] length =  6
local min = (array([ 414,  470,  554,  674,  862, 1000], dtype=int64), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])) length =  2
local mins = [[   0.  414.]
 [   0.  470.]
 [   0.  554.]
 [   0.  674.]
 [   0.  862.]
 [   0. 1000.]] length =  6
```

What am I missing here? Why does dividing instead of subtracting give an out of bounds error for only the part that finds maxima but not the part that finds minima?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does `corrected_spec` look like with each approach? What result do you get from `corrected_spec.loc[corrected_spec["Wavelength (nm)"] == elem]` in each case? Please [try to debug the program yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and if you're still stuck, you can use your findings to help create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Here was my problem: the wavelengths should be spaced by 2 nm. Our labview code has a bug where it occasionally spits out the incorrect exponent. I manually fixed it but made it "985" instead of "986". 

"local_mins[i,0] = corrected_spec.loc[corrected_spec["Wavelength (nm)"] == elem].values[0,0]" Was looking for 986 (because I converted from index to wavelength using [x*2+400 for x in local_min][0]), but did not find it so it returned a shape (0) list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my problem: the wavelengths should be spaced by 2 nm. Our labview code has a bug where it occasionally spits out the incorrect exponent. I manually fixed it but made it "985" instead of "986". "local_mins[i,0] = corrected_spec.loc[corrected_spec["Wavelength (nm)"] == elem].values[0,0]" Was looking for 986 (because I converted from index to wavelength using [x*2+400 for x in local_min][0]), but did not find it so it returned a shape (0) list.